# IMAP protocol violation: EXPUNGE response for unknown messages?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

I have a question about the IMAP protocol (if my server violates it or I misunderstood something):

I am running into a `javax.mail.MessagingException` (caused by `com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException`) because I am trying to access a message which does not exist anymore (actually the connected client never knew about it).

Using Javamail (almost current version, behavior does not change with the current version) I have two application [C1 and C2] accessing one IMAP mailbox/same folder [S].

Both clients [C1 and C2] regularly pull for new messages (using the `javax.mail.Folder.getMessages()` method). If a message is available it is read, deleted and the folder is expunged.

C1 is already connected and regularly does this job. Now C2 also connects and has the following communication with the IMAP server:

```
S: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
C2: a001 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=NTLM AUTH=GSSAPI AUTH=PLAIN STARTTLS UIDPLUS CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
S: a001 OK CAPABILITY completed.
C2: a002 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
S: +
C2: [...]
S: a002 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.
C2: a003 NOOP
S: a003 OK NOOP completed.
C2: a004 NOOP
S: a004 OK NOOP completed.
C2: a005 LIST "" MyFolder
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "/" MyFolder
C2: a005 OK LIST completed.
S: a006 SELECT MyFolder
S: * 0 EXISTS
S: * 0 RECENT
S: * FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 11369] UIDVALIDITY value
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 39] The next unique identifier value
S: a006 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
C2: a007 NOOP
S: a007 OK NOOP completed.
```

Obviously no messages are available, so C2 will just wait a few minutes and check again. Meanwhile C1 checks and receives one message, it flags it as deleted and expunges the folder.

The next time C2 asks for new messages (using the Javamail method mentioned above), my IMAP server returns:

```
C2: a008 NOOP
S: * 1 EXPUNGE
S: * 0 EXISTS
S: a008 OK NOOP completed.
```

Now `javax.mail.Folder.getMessages()` returns one message (with pretty much nothing filled), also `javax.mail.Message.isExpunged()` returns `false`.

Pretty much any method of the Message fails with the exception mentioned above *com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: a010 NO The specified message set is invalid.*

What am I doing wrong here?

- Is my IMAP server reacting strange? Does it violate the IMAP protocol? Should it really inform my client (C2) about one expunged message it never knew?
- Should I not keep the IMAPFolder open in JavaMail to use it later?
- Could it be a bug in JavaMail (of course I do not know every line of the code, but the code seems to be around quite a while)?

Comment: Answered in the [Oracle JavaMail forum](https://community.oracle.com/message/14432779#14432779).

Comment: @BillShannon It seems to me that being told about a non-existent message should be ignored, just like you can request non-existent messages.  Presumably the server did some EXISTS collapsing, somewhat out of order.  This seems unusual, but shouldn't break a client.

Comment: Seems to me the server is broken, but yes, clients always have to work around broken servers.  I'll add another Exchange-specific workaround in JavaMail 1.6.1.